# How to commit after upgrading Drupal?

Tags: svn, drupal

How do I commit changes after I upgraded Drupal? It is actually a new folder to replace the old Drupal site.

I am not sure the way I did is the right way. Because it is a whole new folder, I moved the old trunk files in the repository to a new tag and re-import the new upgraded Drupal as the trunk.

I lost all the svn logs of the old working copy. (in the trunk, I think they are now in the tag)

How should I do Drupal upgrading on a working copy and still keep versioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My process for this is to use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) via the command line to update Drupal core. Drush has svn integration that makes this really easy to do. No need to move your existing trunk out of the way & re-create it (which is problematic, as you've found).

In your working copy, run the following drush command:

```
drush up drupal --svnsync
```

That will pull down the latest Drupal core into your working copy. Files added in the new release will be `svn add`ed. Files removed in the new release will similarly be `svn rm`ed.

The one issue I have encountered with this is that the tarball for the new Drupal release is sometimes marked as "missing" by svn, since it was `add`ed, but no longer exists (because Drush deleted it). The solution to this is simple though - just revert that file:

```
svn revert drupal-[version].tar.gz
```

After all that, commit like normal, and you should be updated to the latest Drupal core. To update modules, you can use drush again, like so:

```
drush up --svnsync
```

Commit changes as before. Now both Drupal core and your third-party modules should be up-to-date.

This process should be done on a local dev site. It will upgrade your database as well as the code. When you push to production, you will need to upgrade its database after you do your normal svn update/switch. That can be done using Drupal's upgrade.php, or using drush:

```
drush updatedb
```

Comment: As it would be hard to improve this answer I'll only add that most people's biggest regret after moving to Git is having put it off so long.

Comment: Exactly what I want to know about and thanks for the great answer.